# strictly positive element in a $C^*$-algebra. Where is the mistake in the proof?

Tags: convergence-divergence, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $a\in A$ a stricly positive element (this means: for all states $\varphi$ of $A$ is $\varphi(a)>0$), let $u_n=a(\frac{1}{n}+a)^{-1}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ . Claim: for all $b\in A$, for all states $\varphi$ of $A$ is $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\varphi(b^*(1-u_n)^2b)=0.$$

I have tried to prove it, but there must be a mistake because I didn't use that $a$ is strictly positive. But I can't find the mistake.

a remark: I still don't know that $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an approximate unit.

My try: Let $\varphi$ a state of $A$, then there exist a Hilbert space $H_\varphi$, a $*$-representation $\pi:A\to L(H)$ with cyclic vector $x_{\pi}$, such that $\|x_{\pi}\|=1$ and $\varphi(a)=\langle \pi(a)x_{\pi},x_{\pi}\rangle$ for all $a\in A$.

Then it is: $$\varphi(b^*(1-u_n)^2b)
\\ =\langle \pi(b^*(1-u_n)^2b)x_{\pi},x_{\pi}\rangle
\\ =\langle \pi(1-u_n)\pi(b)x_{\pi},\pi(1-u_n)\pi(b)x_{\pi}\rangle
\\ =\|\pi(1-u_n)\pi(b)x_{\pi}\|^2 =\|\pi(b-u_nb)x_{\pi}\|^2 \le \|b-u_nb\|^2$$

I think the argument has to be wrong in the following part, where I want to prove that $\|b-u_nb\|\to 0$.

I already know, that $\|a-u_na\|\to 0, \|a-au_n\|\to 0$ for positive $a\in A$.
If $b\in A$ is arbitrary, there are positive elements $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\in A$ such that $b=(b_1-b_2)+i(b_3-b_4)$. Then it is:

$$\|b-u_nb\|=\|(b_1-b_2)+i(b_3-b_4)-u_n[(b_1-b_2)+i(b_3-b_4)]\|
\\ =\|b_1-u_nb_1+u_nb_2-b_2+ib_3-iu_nb_3+iu_nb_4-ib_4\|
\\ \le \|b_1-u_nb_1\|+\|u_nb_2-b_2\|+\|b_3-u_nb_3\|+\|u_nb_4-b_4\|\to 0$$

Here I nowhere use that $a$ is strictly positive. Could you help me to find the mistake?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I already know that  $\|a-au_n\|\to0$ for positive $a $".

No. You know that for your *fixed* $ a $ that happens. There is no reason why, for $a $ not invertible, $b-bu_n\to0$ for arbitrary  $b $.

By the way, you are using that your algebra is unital. In that case, "strictly positive" is simply "positive and invertible".

Comment: oh yes, you are right, I overlooked it. Thanks! Do you know how can I repare it without using, that $(u_n)$ is an approximate unit? I have proven that if $\pi:A\to L(H)$ is a nondegnerate representation, $(\pi(u_n))$ converges to $id_H$ regarding the strong operator-topology. maybe I can use it.

Comment: I could estimate $\|\pi(b-u_nb)x_{\pi}\|^2\le \|id_H-\pi(u_n)\|^2\|\pi(b)\|^2$ but it seems to be pointless

Comment: Since you are using that $A $ is unital (which sounds strange to me, with the talk about strict positivity) you simply show that  $a (1/n+a)^{-1}\to1$ in $C^*(a) $ using functional calculus. As $a $ is invertible in $A $, the unit of $C^*(a) $ is the unit of $A $.

Comment: okay, I understand! I thought that the requierement that $A$ is unital is implicit contained in the claim (I hope, you can understand it, my English is poor)

Comment: Probably not. Even if $A $ is non-unital, you can think of it inside its unitization and still $a (1/n+a)^{-1} $ and $b^*(1-u_n)^2b $ are in $A $.

Comment: okay thanks. I started a littlebit different now: $\varphi$ defines a scalar product $\langle (1-u_n)^2b,b\rangle=\varphi(b^*(1-u_n)^2b)$ on $A$. Then, $\varphi(b^*(1-u_n)^2b)=\langle (1-u_n)^2b,b\rangle =\langle (1-u_n)b,(1-u_n)b\rangle =\|(1-u_n)b\|^2$ but I must prove now, that $(u_n)$ is a approximate unit in $A$.